# How does typescript type Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

How does typescript type Promise.all()
In the resolved array of values, how is typescript able to infer the type of each item? I only see one Generic T in the type signature of Promise.all(), but why am I able to pass in promises that resolve to different types of values?

To elaborate, why does my promiseAll implementation throws typescript type error but the built-in one work like magic?

```js
const promiseAll = function<T>(promises: Promise<T>[]): Promise<T[]> {
  const results: T[] = [];
  let completedCount = 0;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    promises.forEach(function(promise, index) {
      promise.then(function (value) {
        results[index] = value;
        completedCount += 1;
        if(completedCount === promises.length) {
          resolve(results);
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}

const promise1 = new Promise<number>(resolve => setTimeout(() => { resolve(1) }, 500));
const promise2 = new Promise<string>(resolve => setTimeout(() => { resolve("a") }, 500));



async function main() {
    const [value1, value2] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
    const [myValue1, myValue2] = await promiseAll([promise1, promise2]);
}

main();
```

Comment: Your implementation doesn't work because when you say `Promise<T>[]` you are notating an array of Promises where each Promise have the same type. So when you pass a promise of `number` and `string` it fails. I don't know exactly how Typescript infers the type. I would assume it just casts it to `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript types `Promise.all` with 11 overloads, but this approach only allows up to a finite number of `PromiseLike` objects with different types to be passed in. One of the overloads is able to handle an array of any length filled with consistently typed `PromiseLike` objects, though. Here are two of the overloads for an example:

```
Promise.all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>, T4 | PromiseLike<T4>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>
Promise.all<T>(values: readonly (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>
```

The `Promise.all` overloads with independently typed arguments seem to support only up to 9 distinctly typed elements in the `values` argument.

The code you've given as an example matches the second overload above quite closely, but has the same limitation in that it will only work if the type of every `Promise` in the array passed to `Promise.all` is the same.

Your example would compile if you told TypeScript you were passing an array of type `Promise<number | string>[]` to `PromiseAll`, because then all of your `Promise`s would be treated as having the same type. Though then of course the array you get back out would be of type `(number | string)[]` and you wouldn't know which element had which type.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to achieve a generic type signature for Promise.all. Here is an example using Box/Unbox which can be adapted for Promises by replacing Box with Promise and Unbox with Awaited and adding async keywords where necessary.

Note: such type-level meta programming can cause performance issues for the type checker. It is sometimes more sensible to implement N overloads.

```
class Box<T> {
    v: T;

    constructor(v: T) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    unbox(): T {
        return this.v
    }
}

type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer H, ...infer _] ? H : any;
type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer _, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : any[];
type Unbox<T> = T extends Box<infer R> ? R : never;
type UnboxArr<T extends Box<any>[], B extends any[] = []> =
  T["length"] extends 0 ? B : UnboxArr<Tail<T>, [...B, Unbox<Head<T>>]>;

function unboxAll<T extends Box<any>[]>(...args: T): UnboxArr<T> {
    return args.map(x => x.unbox()) as any
}

function foo() {
    const [a, b] = unboxAll(new Box(123), new Box("abc"));
    bar(a, b)
}

function bar(a: number, b: string) {
    console.log(a, b);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2APAPAFQHzQN4FgBQ0h0AbgFzSoDc%20%20R0w8AdhAC4BOArsC-GwBRkKASmy06RFgAsAlhAB0xaAF4S1AkQC%20NdYQ6MARkj5DyqUTvFsApiw5tG0KbIVjCWvO-wsAngAcr0AASVmAAJmjQVogsVoyhMGCM3gDaALqYKmZRMXEwydKMAGZWbEEANNByVQXFpQD6qdAA-EHQ5Ineaj7%20FGDSIBHZsfHQHWkZFJHRw3k1JdB1FVVyc6UASlasjS0brG2jSWldfgEAqgZIaBNZ07lwl6vQa5g7%204xWxCXHPeeGiACCbDYg1uIwQKA66DSFVgUxyIzGjRU42UYlQyQARCBYgBzKQYxpDO4ABmacH2vyQgOBqD6AwwFWSy1gFUpKGCYSu6HSanwhT03GkTGgej%20-xA9LhM3uEKSUPSfGWYDYOIgphM0DZ1Ku5jo1ls9lGKvkAFswL4%20IhlJhEHJRUYhCJIAdvPhPHh%20YxBcLCvB4MZdUQGMwWNBkmAKvokSKLgCJXx3gB3GV8ACMACYAMxCCpJlMYsD6YAYx1qOj6ZV8CPQfRCN3aT3ehwV-hgciMDgm-QlSPkVhsAo4kS4CzBiDwbFyEDwHFVyNCNQaIA)